# Confusion over Base Activity and Top Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service

My app starts a `Service` (in the same process) and also launches another app. In my `Service` I have some code to investigate the running tasks:

```
private void logBaseAndTopActivities() {
    ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<RunningTaskInfo> taskInfoList = activityManager.getRunningTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    for(RunningTaskInfo taskInfo : taskInfoList){
        Log.d(TAG, "Base: " + taskInfo.baseActivity.getPackageName());
        Log.d(TAG, "Top: " + taskInfo.topActivity.getPackageName());
    }
}
```

Before I launch the other app I get output like:

```
Base: com.example.myApp
Top: com.example.myApp
```

After I launch the other app from my `Activity`, I get output like:

```
Base: com.example.otherApp
Top: com.example.otherApp
```

But I was expecting to see:

```
Base: com.example.myApp
Top: com.example.otherApp
```

since if I press the back button from `otherApp` it takes me back to `myApp`. What am I misunderstanding?

Also, how can I determine if the foreground app was launched from `myApp`? The documentation says that `getRunningTasks()` is not safe to use, but that currently the first entry will be the foreground app.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about this. But,

### You are starting an activity of another app.

The baseActivity(docs) says :

> The component launched as the first activity in the task. This can be considered the "application" of this task.

Here, the task is considered as the application. So the android system launches another task for another app and sets the baseActivity as com.example.otherApp.

Instead, Try Starting an Activity from the same app and see the result.
Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: When you launch an activity, it can either go into the same task, or a different task. This depends on a lot of factors, including the activity configuration in the manifest, the current state of the application and the launch flags that you set on the `Intent` that you pass to `startActivity()`.

Answer (score 0):

I am now seeing the results I was expecting to see. I am not sure why. It seems like it must be my error. The only other thing I have to go on is that I shut down another instance of `otherApp` (started outside `myApp`) due to some problem and then things were working fine.

Comment: Well, it depends on how the other app is configured (manifest) and also how you launch the other app. This is probably not a reliably repeatable behaviour. If the other app is already running (ie: was launched by the user directly) and you then launch it, it is possible that the activity you launch is reparented to another task. This means that you can't be sure if the activity (of the other app) that you launch will end up in your task or another task.